# select columns from two tables and put the result in one colum in a specific order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables : a table PERSON, and a table CAR. there is a one to many relatshionship between the two tables : One person can own multiple cars, and one car can be owned by one and only one person.

The table PERSON has the following columns:

```
    PERSON
          PERSON_ID
          PERSON_NAME
```

The table CAR has the following columns:

```
    CAR
          CAR_ID
          CAR_DESCRIPTION
          PERSON_ID (the owner)
```

The content of the two tables is as follows:

```
    PERSON
    PERSON_ID    PERSON_NAME
    -------------------------
    1            John
    2            Karl
    3            Sarah
    4            Kevin
    --------------------------

    CAR
    CAR_ID    CAR_DESCRIPTION       PERSON_ID (owner)
    -----------------------------------------
    1            Mercedes            3
    2            Honda               3
    3            Hundai              1
```

I want to use the above tables to get a table result similar to the following:

```
    Result:
    john
    Hundai
    karl
    sarah
    mercedes
    honda
    kevin
```

In other words, I want to get a result table composed of one column where I show the owner followed by all the cars he owns; then the next person followed by the cars he owns (if any)..etc

Can this be done at the database level ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle? Your accepted answer will **not** work with Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or simply

```
select descr from (
select -1 as car_id, person_id, person_name as descr from person
union all
select car_id, person_id, car_description as descr from car
order by 2,1)
```

Comment: Much better answer (and will actually work with Oracle unlike the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution -

```
with person as 
(
    select 1 as PERSON_ID, 'John' as PERSON_NAME from dual union all
    select 2 as PERSON_ID, 'Karl' as PERSON_NAME from dual union all
    select 3 as PERSON_ID, 'Sarah' as PERSON_NAME from dual union all
    select 4 as PERSON_ID, 'Kevin'  as PERSON_NAME from dual
),
car as 
(
    select 1 as CAR_ID, 'Mercedes' as CAR_DESCRIPTION, 3 as PERSON_ID from dual union all
    select 2 as CAR_ID, 'Honda' as CAR_DESCRIPTION,    3 as PERSON_ID from dual union all
    select 3 as CAR_ID, 'Hundai' as CAR_DESCRIPTION,   1 as PERSON_ID from dual
)
select lower(nm) as nm
from
   (select PERSON_ID as ID, null as PRN_ID, PERSON_NAME as NM 
      from person
    union all
    select CAR_ID as ID, PERSON_ID as PRN_ID, CAR_DESCRIPTION as NM
      from car)
order by nvl(prn_id, id)
```

and using the hierarchical query -

```
select lower(nm) as nm
from
   (select 1 as TP, PERSON_ID as ID, null as PRN_ID, PERSON_NAME as NM 
     from person
    union all
    select 2 as TP, CAR_ID as ID, PERSON_ID as PRN_ID, CAR_DESCRIPTION as NM
    from car)
connect by (prior id = prn_id) and ((prior tp = 1) and (tp = 2))
  start with prn_id is null
  order siblings by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use cursor for this task.

```
DECLARE @person_name NVARCHAR(150),
        @last_person_name NVARCHAR(150),
        @car_description NVARCHAR(150)

DECLARE @result_tbl TABLE(value NVARCHAR(150))

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT P.person_name, C.car_description FROM Person AS P
                           LEFT JOIN Car AS C ON P.person_id = C.person_id

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @person_name, @car_description

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @person_name <> ISNULL(@last_person_name, '')
        INSERT INTO @result_tbl
        VALUES(@person_name)

    SET @last_person_name = @person_name

    IF @car_description IS NOT NULL
        INSERT INTO @result_tbl
        VALUES(@car_description)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @person_name, @car_description
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM @result_tbl
```

Comment: This is invalid for Oracle and is far too complicated. This can be done with a single SQL query.